# Different version R installed in the same system (ubuntu, linux), how to pick which one to run?

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu

I had R-2.14 installed before. 
And I just installed R-3.1.1 from a tar.gz file.

Now if I use command

```
user$R
```

I will bring up the R-2.14.

I can only use R-3.1.1 by command:

```
user$~/R3installedFolder/R/bin/R
```

Question:
How can I configure "R" as the command to bring up R-3.1.1? 
I am new to Linux/Ubuntu. I want to keep both Rs in the same system.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is to set the correct version to run by setting the appropriate values in `update-alternatives`.  Take a look at the [***Ubuntu manpages***](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) for more details.

My guess is that you need to run `update-alternatives --config <your program>`.

---

e.g. from the man page:

> To  choose  a  particular vi implementation, use this command as root
>   and then select a number from the list:
>
> ```
> update-alternatives --config vi
> ```